# Задача красивые числа

Tags: python

Условие задачи:

Красивое число — это число, состоящее из уникальных цифр. Например, 222, 8, 5555 —
красивые числа, а 34, 5505 и 12345 — нет.
Ваша задача по данным двум целым числам l и r найти количество красивых чисел в
интервале [l..r].
Входные данные
В единственной строке даны два целых числа l и r
Выходные данные
Выведите одно целое число — ответ на задачу

Помогите откорректировать код или при нужде поменять его полностью!! Спасибо большое заранее!!!
Мой код:

```
l, r = input('Введите диапозон чисел например 42 100, т.е. 42-100: ').split(' ')

l = int(l)
r = int(r)
count = 0

for i in range(l, r):
  i = str(i)
  amount_of_words = len(i)
  for k in range(0, amount_of_words):
    if i[k] == i[k+1]:
      

print(count)
```

Comment: а зачем его корректировать или менять?

Comment: вы меня не поняли, этот код не является решением задачи, а всего лишь эскиз

Comment: нет, это вы не поняли куда пришли. Тут не решают загадки на тему "догадайтесь что я хотел спросить" и "догадайтесь что мой код делает не так и исправьте его". Если это всего лишь эскиз, то делайте из него финальный продукт. Или изменяйте вопрос так, чтобы он содержал ясную конкретную проблему.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ну в таком случае вопрос, помочь решить задачу!

Comment: Не перебирайте все числа подряд. Напишите цикл, перебирающий только красивые числа. (Подсказка: красивое число описывается двумя числами: числом знаков и цифрой от 1 до 9).

Comment: я понял вашу идею, но не могли бы вы помочь, как перебрать только красивые числа, именно на этом моменте у меня стоит главный вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно из числа сделать строку, ведь её легче будет проверить, и твой код тоже имеет хоть какое-то значение, в твой код я чуть-чуть добавил поправок, и вот что вышло

```
l, r = input().split(' ')
l = int(l)
r = int(r)

count = 0

for i in range(l, r, 1): # step не обязательно, просто я уже к нему привык
  i = str(i)
  if i.count(i[0]) == len(i):
    count += 1
  else:
    continue

print(count)
```

То есть мы проверяем, если количество первого знака строки совпадает с его длиной, то это и есть красивое число, иначе мы его пропускаем, если мы не напишем

```
  else:
    continue
```

То будет выдаваться ошибка (**SyntaxError**)

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

алгоритм простой - как я понял вам надо определить, что число состоит из одних и тех же цифр?

есть несколько способов решения:

в этом случае с числом лучше всего работать как со строкой

**вариант 1:**

проверяйте сколько раз в строке встречается первый символ - для этого есть метод `.count()`

**вариант 2:**

можно посмотреть какие вообще уникальные символы (по сути цифры) есть в строке - для этого есть объект "множество" (`set`) - переведите строку в множество

ну а если работать с числом - то можно получить цифры числа по следующему алгоритму

**вариант 1:**

пока число не будет равно 0:

- определяем остаток от деления числа на 10 (через `%`)
- делим нацело число на 10 (через `//`)

Answer (score 0):

В общих чертах так: можно задать целочисленную маску вида `111` (единицы, не путать с переменной `l`) со стартовым количеством разрядов как у `l` (начального числа), потом в цикле умножать маску на числа от `1` до `9` - это и будут красивые числа (умножать маску на `0` нужно только в одном случае - если стартовое число == 0). После достижения `9` нарастить маску на один разряд - и снова умножать маску на числа от `1` до `9` - и так до тех пор, пока красивое число не превосходит `r`. Считать только те КЧ, которые не менее `l` (начального числа).
При таком подходе перебирать числа и проверять цифры в них не придётся, они сразу генерируются "красивыми", нужно только проверять границы.

Разница в производительности на больших числах будет существенной:

- чтобы с помощью `for i in range(l, r):` найти следующее красивое число после, например, 11111, нужно будет перебрать более 11 тысяч чисел (22222-11111).
- по данному алгоритму следующее подходящее красивое число формируется за две операции: умножение (11111*2 = 22222) плюс проверка на предмет нахождения числа внутри установленных границ.

```
left, right = 213, 1234
mask = int('1' * len(str(left)))  # маска вида 111, которая при умножении на число 0..9 дает "красивое число"

counter, num = 0, 0
while num <= right:
    for d in range(0 if num == 0 else 1,10):  # начинаем с нуля только первый цикл
        num = mask * d
        if left <= num <= right:
            counter += 1
            print(num)
    mask = mask * 10 + 1

print(f'`Красивых чисел` в диапазоне [{left} ... {right}]: {counter}')
```

```
222
333
444
555
666
777
888
999
1111
`Красивых чисел` в диапазоне [213 ... 1234]: 9
```